# Possibly leaving temple

Tags: scripture, guru

Jai Sri Mā!

I have attended a temple for many years. A lot of things changed after COVID (not just due to it, but many changes having happened to occur during that time). I had attended there more in the past, but have been going less and less. I do not want to go into great detail, but I do not feel the same or have the same relationship with the temple as before. I took diksha from my Guruji there.

The issue I am facing is this:

1. Because I took diksha from a guru there, am I bound by shastras to remain there?
2. I do virtually all my worship at home. Am I bound by shastras to attend temple?

Dandabat.

Jai Sri Mā!

Comment: Depends. You need to ask your guru. He/she will give you permission to go. There are multiple times a guru tells their disciple to go, or sometimes even the disciple leaves. But you might have to take an oath to always keep the devta (or ishvara) in your heart and keep coming there in the future occasionally if possible as a good gesture.